# Abstract Class Declarations

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I saw this question online, and i would like to know if i am doing this correctly or not. The site does not list the answer or guides.

The question

Write the declaration only for the abstract class **Animal**. **Animal** should contain attributes for **name** and **age**, and functions **display**, **setFields** and **concrete**. Write the declaration and implementation, of a class **Tiger** derived from **Animal**, with the **Tiger** having overridden functions which were appropriate, use the base class one. The **Tiger** has additional data fields associated with **strips**(an integer) and **tailLength**.

I would appericate, if you can tell if i am doing it correctly.

Animal class

```
 class Animal{
  private:
  string name;
  int age;
  public:
  void display();
  void setFields(string, int);
  void concrete();
};
```

Tiger class

```
 class Tiger:public Animal{
 private:
 int strips;
 int tailLength;
 public:
 void display();
 void setFields(string, int, int, int);
};
```

Comment: I'm curious. What's `strips` for?

Comment: Maybe it's *stripes* (as in "number of") ?

Comment: @MarkGarcia Its just another attribute specifically  for the tiger class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want derived classes to be able to override base class methods, you need to make these `virtual`. Otherwise your derived classes will just hide the name of the methods you were intending to override. You should also [provide a virtual destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors).

```
class Animal{
  private:
  std::string name;
  int age;
  public:
  virtual void display();
  virtual void setFields(string, int);
  virtual void concrete();
  virtual ~Animal() {}
};
```

It is not clear what the assignment means about an *abstract* base class. Usually this means at least one [*pure virtual method*](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pure-virtual-fns.html) is not implemented. But the assignment mentions using the base class implementations where appropriate, which means you should provide some implementations in `Animal`.

Answer (score 2):

An abstract class uses pure-virtual member functions:

```
class Animal{
  private:
  string name;
  int age;
  public:
  virtual void display() = 0;
  virtual void setFields(string, int) = 0;
  virtual void concrete() = 0;
  virtual ~Animal() { }
};
```

Not all of them would necessarily be pure virtual, but at least one of them has to be in order for the class to be considered abstract.